# Using a loop to change or check value of input

Tags: c

I need this function to check whether the upper_bound is being inputed less than the lower_bound. If it is, an error should appear and it should ask for a new upper_bound. I don't know how to replace the value of the upper_bound with a new user input.

```
void inputs(double *coefficient_a, double *coefficient_b, double *coefficient_c, double *lower_bound, double *upper_bound, int *number_of_steps)
{ 
  printf("Enter coefficient A -> ");
  scanf("%lf", coefficient_a);
  printf("Enter coefficient B -> ");
  scanf("%lf", coefficient_b);
  printf("Enter coefficient C -> ");
  scanf("%lf", coefficient_c);
  printf("Enter lower bound -> ");
  scanf("%lf", lower_bound);
  printf("Enter upper bound -> ");
  scanf("%lf", upper_bound);
  do
  {
    if (upper_bound < lower_bound)
    {
      printf("\nError: upper bound must be greater than lower bound!");
    }
    printf("\nEnter upper bound -> ");
    scanf("%lf", upper_bound);
  } while (upper_bound < lower_bound);

  printf("Enter number of steps for trapezoidal sum -> ");
  scanf("%i", number_of_steps);
  return;
}
```

Comment: `if (upper_bound < lower_bound)` <- you're comparing pointers here. Is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: *"I don't know how to replace the value of the upper_bound with a new user input.*" You're already doing that.

Comment: Just use if(* upper_bound < * lower_bound ) in your current code. Currently you're comparing of address of upper_bound is lesser than address of lower_bound

Answer (score 1):

You should just add assignment * to upper_bound and lower_bound in 'if' and 'while' conditions. Without *, you are comparing two pointers, not their values (values pointed by pointers). * means that pointer is going to get dereferenced.

```
void inputs(double *coefficient_a, double *coefficient_b, double *coefficient_c, double *lower_bound, double *upper_bound, int *number_of_steps) {
    printf("Enter coefficient A -> ");
    scanf("%lf", coefficient_a);
    printf("Enter coefficient B -> ");
    scanf("%lf", coefficient_b);
    printf("Enter coefficient C -> ");
    scanf("%lf", coefficient_c);
    printf("Enter lower bound -> ");
    scanf("%lf", lower_bound);
    printf("Enter upper bound -> ");
    scanf("%lf", upper_bound);
    do {
        if (*upper_bound < *lower_bound) {
            printf("\nError: upper bound must be greater than lower bound!");
        }
        printf("\nEnter upper bound -> ");
        scanf("%lf", upper_bound);
    } while (*upper_bound < *lower_bound);

    printf("Enter number of steps for trapezoidal sum -> ");
    scanf("%i", number_of_steps);
    return;
}
```

Remember to dereference pointers when you want to use their values.

Quick explanation: upper_bound and lower_bound are pointers (i.e their values are address), therefore (upper_bound < lower_bound) is to compare address, not the value stored at these address. Your first part (using scanf to get input data) is fine because scanf needs a pointer as a parameter. However, in your loop and if condition, you need to add * to upper_bound and lower_bound to get dereferenced values. **Warning: You can't call your function like this**:

```
double a = 2,b = 3,c = 4,lower = 5,upper = 6,steps = 7;
inputs(a,b,c,lower,upper,steps);
```

Because this way you are passing values, not adresses. **You should use & operator** to get an address of a variable.

Comment: You say `Without *, you are comparing two pointers, not their values.`

This is slightly wrong. Technically the * tells the compiler to reference the value in memory the pointer is pointing to. The value of the pointer is technically the address of the memory location where the "value" you want is stored.

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple. * is dereferencing pointer. By values, i meant values pointed by pointers. Good catch, I'm going to include it in answer.